# Compare two (2) date

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I want to compare two date `date` and `date2`.

```
Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(HTML.date("DATE ", Unit.Percentage(100), "", datefrom)).Render();
Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(HTML.date("DATE2 ", Unit.Percentage(100), "", dateto)).Render();
```

This the JavaScript method when I want to test if my date `DATE` and `DATE1` are valid, i.e. if `DATE1>DATE`.

```
<script>
function sentval() {
  debugger;
  datefrom = DATE .GetText();
  dateTo = DATE2.GetText();

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Dashboarding/Liste?datefrom=" + datefrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo ,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'text',       
    success: function (data) {
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Editors/DateRangePicker

Answer (score 0):

Use the client-side [ASPxClientDateEdit.GetDate](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientDateEdit_GetDatetopic) method instead to retrieve the underlying Date JavaScript value:

```
//datefrom = DATE.GetText();
//dateTo = DATE2.GetText();

datefrom = DATE.GetDate();
dateTo = DATE2.GetDate();
```

Then, perform the necessary DateTime comparison operations on the Controller side (it seems that you are passing these values as a part of the URL).

Answer (score -1):

```
 var  dateFrom = new Date(DATE.GetText());
 var dateTo = new Date(DATE2.GetText());
if(dateTo.getTime() >dateFrom.getTime()){
 //DATE2 is greater
}else{
 //DATE is greater
}
```

> Note :getTime() Return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01